# Javascript regex to match equal number of consecutive 1 and 0

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a regex which matches following scenarios,

```
10
1100
111000
11110000
// etc. consecutive 1 count should equal consecutive 0 count.
```

Is it possible to write a regex for this?
I suppose I could write, `1{n}0{n}`, but it didn't work here: https://regex101.com/

**May be this is not doable with regex?**

I can of course do this with a loop. But I want to know if this is possible using regex.

Thank you!!!!

Comment: Not sure this is possible with a single regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically the answer is no.

We can write regular expressions for strings that belong to regular languages.
Your case belong to a context free language.